# notice php - alternative or remove?

Tags: php, notice

i am using this code to check if the variables `$n0, $n1, $n2` are not defined.

But i get a notice each time that was not defined. My code is a bad practice? there is any alternative? or just remove the notices and the code is fine?

```
            if (!isset ($n0) && $n0 != $form['name0']){
                echo ("n0");
            }

            if (!isset ($n1) && $n1 != $form['name1']) {
                echo ("n1");
            }

            if (!isset ($n2) && $n2 != $form['name2']) {
                echo ("n2");
            }
```

thanks

Comment: You should treat notices as errors while developing and debugging. There's always a better, less error-prone way to do something if PHP is yelling at you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should actually be replacing those `&&`'s with `||`'s.  If the `$n`'s aren't set then they surely won't equal the `$form` values..

This will prevent the notices and do what you're intending